# How can I convert a System.Char to a System.Windows.Input.Key?

Tags: wpf

In XAML I can do this:

```
<KeyBinding Command="{Binding UndoCommand}"
            Key="Z"
           Modifiers="Control"/>
```

But now I want to implement this in the code behind:

```
dim binding=New KeyBinding(someCommand,ConvertToKey("Z"), ModifierKeys.Control)
```

How does the "ConvertToKey" function really look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key is an enum, u can convert string to enum thru

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(Key),"Z")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! It only works for some strings though. Some strings cannot be converted. I will have to find a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

In code behind this could be implemented as:

```
new KeyBinding(someCommand, Key.Z, ModifierKeys.Control)
```

Comment: Sorry, The "Z" is a variable. How do I convert "Z" to Key.Z, "A" to Key.A, etc.  ?